# What is the significance of .h file in a static library?

Tags: ios, macos, static-libraries

I am a new iOS developer. I got a very basic doubt. I read at many places that we need to ship our .h file along with a .a file for a static library.

And .a files are compiled libraries, having entire implementation, which developers cannot read themselves, just to safe-guard implementer code.

And we need .h file to know what public functions are available. but then why cannot Xcode just decode .a file and use it directly instead of shipping another .h file. Xcode doesn't need to show the .a implementation to developers, but instead can suggest developers with publicly available methods.

I dont see any logical reason why Apple didnt do this way. I am sure there is definitely a strong reason for shipping .h files. I want to know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `.a` file is simply an archive of one or more `.o` (object) files. Object files contain the compiled machine code (for one specific operating system under a specific CPU architecture). The original source code is "lost".

The fact you probably didn't know about: object files can contain binaries compiled from an arbitrary programming language. An `.h` file is C/C++/Objective C specific. It contains the data types and function prototypes you need to be able to use the functions/data types/... contained in binary form in an object file in C/C++/Objective C. You could e.g. write a Pascal library, compile it to a `.a` file and use that code in your Objective C program using an appropriate header (`.h`) file.

You could also have only one header file (`.h` file) but e.g. 6 different `.a` files: One compiled for `Mac OS X 64bit`, one for `Mac OS X 32bit`, one for `Linux 2.6 64bit`, one for `Linux 2.6 32bit`, one for `FreeBSD` and the last for `OpenBSD`.

And last but not least, it wasn't Apple who decided to go that way, `.a` and `.o` files can be found on (at least) any Unix-like operating system and header files are the standard in C since the very first days.

Usually if you port a library from Mac to Linux, you can use (most of) the code and the header file but have to compile a separate `.a` file containing the object files compiled for Linux.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed reply. but still as the .a code is architecture specific, why cannot an editor read the .a files, and show us what public functions available, as during execution, executable is able to link the required function in static library. so why cannot the editor do the same.

This is just for my logical understanding.

Comment: It is very simple to read a function's name from a `.o` file (so it's very simple from a `.a` file, too), BUT: You cannot easily know how many and what type of parameter(s) and return value the function has! The ABI (application binary interface) defines what to do with parameters, usually they are only pushed onto the stack one after another. The machine code in the `.o` file then loads the data from there. But it's not easily possible to always reverse engineer this.

Answer (score 0):

the `.a` files are collection of compiled `.c`, `.c++`, `.m` etc files.  Decompilng those files just to get the names / signatures of functions would a) be dodgy on moral/privacy grounds and b) be a lot of work.  The `.a` files aren't byte code or something similarly easy to reverse engineer - they are machine code.

Even if you did reverse engineer the "source" from those compiled files, they wouldn't contain the actual method names, or signatures, or anything recognisable.